# Working with Cython in PyCharm - how to run compiled files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, cython

I'm trying to find out how to work with Cython and face some problems.
I'm using python 3.6 and PyCharm Professional as IDE. Current environment is OSX.

First of all I tried to create a simple app containing two files:
common.pyx:

```
cpdef cppfun(t):
    s = 0
    for i in range(t):
        for j in range(t):
            s = s + i*j
    return s

def pyfun(t):
    s = 0
    for i in range(t):
        for j in range(t):
            s = s + i*j
    return s
```

and main file that I'm trying to run in PyCharm.
As I understand it's necessary to compile my common.pyx to ".so" file. To do it I create setup.py file with following content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("cmn", ["common.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"], extra_compile_args=["-ffast-math"])
]

setup(
  name="cmn",
  cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

and run in terminal this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Therefore I'm trying to import compiled file to my runner.py:

```
import time
from ctypes import cdll
cmn = cdll.LoadLibrary('../cmn.cpython-36m-darwin.so')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 100000
    start_time = time.time()
    cmn.pyfun(count)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    cmn.cppfun(count)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

But got error:

> File "/path-to-env/lib/python3.6/ctypes/**init**.py", line 366, in
>   **getitem**
>       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self)) AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fb77cd02120, pyfun): symbol not found

Eventually, I don't know how to make it work.
I have an idea that I have to use:

```
from common import pyfun, cppfun
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
```

and avoid manual compilation via terminal, but in this case I get following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'

Comment: I would look at the `Run/Debug Configurations` in Run > Edit Configurations. There you can add new configuration which runs `setup.py build_ext --inplace`. One question: Why are you adding the library with LoadLibrary()? Why not using import?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, regarding `LoadLibrary()` usage - I'm a new one in cython, so I misunderstood how to work with it. Surely, it's much more correct to use compilation via `setup.py build_ext --inplace`